# How to select distinct combinations in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, devexpress

I'm using SQL in **Devexpress dashboard designer**. I want to select distinct combinations of two parameters.
Perhaps Devexpress uses Transact-SQL but at the same time `GROUP BY` clause never works for me.
At the same time `DISTINCT BY` somehowe doesn't work as well.

*Example:*

There are two IDs 11 and 22
And there are two values of Date for 11, as an example: 21.01.2000 and 22.01.2000. And there's one for 22 as an example: 23.05.2008

Problem here is that I can't coose `DISTINCT` by date because there are many other IDs which have the same dates.

So I expect to have one distinct combination of ID and Date.

Does anyone faced with the same problem, can you advice any solution / code example?

Comment: Sample data, and expected results, will help us help you.

Comment: I will provide those in the discription. Thank you for the advice

Answer (score 0):

Using `select distinct` will filter duplicates if you leave unique row properties out of the selected fields.

so:

```
Mike Smit
Mike Smit
```

Will be reduced to

```
Mike Smit
```

But if you're also asking for a PK like a Id field you get the following because id makes both rows distinct

```
1 Mike Smit
2 Mike Smit
```

Does this help?

Comment: I'm not talking about distinct values itsef but about combination. If you tried to provide this as the solution please write code example.

Comment: Ok that was not clear for me from your post. Do you have a example of fields and maybe the current instructions you're trying to execute in which group by and such is not working out? ;)

Comment: I just want to select distinct combination of data and ID